# ng-if not working with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-if

This should be a simple issue, but I don't understand what's happening. 
Basically I'm passing an object to a function call in my controller with ng-if withing an ng-repeat. 
However my function doesn't see the param passed to it. It says undefined.

```js
var app = angular.module('newformController', []);

app.controller('NewFormController', ['$scope', '$log',
            function($scope, $log) {
              
     $scope.meta = {
      "GRANT": {
        "VALUE": "2",
        "DEFAULT": "1",
        "RANGE": "1:4",
        "TYPE": "INTEGER",
        "DESCRIPTION": "Some description"
      }
    };

    $scope.testing = function(x) {
        $log.debug('X is: ' + x);
        if (x == "1:4") {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    };
    
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<tr ng-repeat="(param,value) in meta">
  <td>{{param}}</td>
  <td>{{value.DESCRIPTION}}</td>
  <span ng-if="testing(value.RANGE)">
                  <td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{value.DEFAULT}}"></td>
              </span>
</tr>
```

Why does the console print 'undefine' ? And why does the function get call so many times? I only have one key, shouldn't ng-repeat just loop only once?

[image]

Now if I instead of "value.RANGE" pass some string to the function, the string will be read/printed correctly...

Comment: Angular will run `digest` cycle for each iteration of `ng-repeat`. You should use one way bind.

Comment: probably because your html is invalid ...browser probably kicking that span out of table and therefore outside of the child scope

Comment: Your html seems to be invalid - for a quick example i just swapped you html to divs, check out this exmaple - http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16354/

Comment: @Vineet, how do you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have invalid html - check out this example - http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/16355/

I just modified your table code to look like this

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="(param,value) in meta">
        <td>{{param}}</td>
        <td>{{value.DESCRIPTION}}</td>
        <td ng-if="testing(value.RANGE)">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{value.DEFAULT}}">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And it works :).

Answer (score 1):

If you use valid html it works fine

```
<tr ng-repeat="(param,value) in meta">
  <td>{{param}}</td>
  <td>{{value.DESCRIPTION}}</td>

  <td ng-if="testing(value.RANGE)">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{value.DEFAULT}}">
  </td>

</tr>
```

`<span>` is not a valid child of `<tr>` so browser is likely moving it outside of the table and therefore outside of the `ng-repeat` child scope. Then when angular runs that function it is in different scope

[working version](http://plnkr.co/edit/dnraOuWgoyHbdVxrFIgk?p=preview)